# Can't apply the logic of grabbing next pages within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I've created a script using `axios` and `cheerio` to fetch different shop names and their associated links from [yellowpages](https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA) and then used those links to scrape phone and email from their inner pages. The script is doing fine.

What I wish to do now is use the [next page link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW1vB.jpg) to keep grabbing the content from next pages as well. I just can't figure out how to apply the logic of parsing and using next pages within `getLinks()` function.

At the moment this is what I'm trying with:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const startUrl = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA';
const host = 'https://www.yellowpages.com';

const getLinks = async (url,host,callback) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url);
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);
      $('[class="result"] a.business-name').each(function(){
        let items = $(this).find('span').text();
        let links = host + $(this).attr("href");
        return callback(items,links);
      });
}

const fetchContent = async (shopName,shopLink,callback) => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(shopLink);
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);
      let phone = $('.contact > p.phone').eq(0).text();
      let email = $('.business-card-footer > a.email-business').eq(0).attr("href");
      return callback(shopName,shopLink,phone,email);
}

async function scrapeData() {
  getLinks(startUrl,host,function(itemName,link){
    fetchContent(itemName,link,function(shopName,shopLink,phone,email){
      console.log({shopName,shopLink,phone,email});
    });
  });
}

scrapeData();
```

Comment: This is easy.Click on that link and see what the url look like.maybe they have a selection as per how many results can be shown. Maybe they have an API?  Ok, the easiest without an API would be click the link, save that as startUrl2 and iterate through that. But the best would be to fill an array with all the urls and the iterate through all urls in the array. But you need to check the url after clicking on next. And see if theres an option to display 1000 or 100 results per page.

Answer (score 1):

Next page links are often in `[rel=next]` so it's usually something like this:

```
async function get(url) {
  const { data } = await axios.get(url);
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  return $
}

async function run(){
  let url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Pizza&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA'
  let $ = await get(url)
  // doSomething($)
  let href = $('[rel=next]').attr('href')
  while(href){
    url = new URL(href, url).href
    $ = await get(url)
    // doSomething($)
    href = $('[rel=next]').attr('href')
  }
}
```